# Update function not working with Angular and WEB api

Tags: html, .net, angular, typescript, .net-core

I am making a CRUD example with dotnet cor and angular I have made a function in the backend like this:

**CarController.cs**

```
 [Route("UpdateCar")]
        [HttpPut]
        public IActionResult Put([FromBody] Car car, long id)
        {
            var c = _context.Cars.First(e => e.CarId == id);
            c.Brand = car.Brand;
            c.Color = car.Color;
            c.Model = car.Model;
            c.LastChange = DateTime.Now;
            c.TopSpeed = car.TopSpeed;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
```

I am calling this method in my carservice like this:

```
 updateCar(carvm: CarVM): Observable<CarVM> {
   const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    return this.http.put<CarVM>(this.baseUrl, carvm, httpOptions)
  }
```

And I use this method to get a specific car:

```
 getCarById(carId: string): Observable<CarVM> {
    return this.http.get<CarVM>(this.baseUrl + "/UpdateCar?id=" + carId)
  }
```

I call this method in my component like this:

```
EditCar(CarId: string) {
    this.carservice.getCarById(CarId).subscribe(Response => {
      this.dataSaved = false;
      this.Carid = Response.CarId;
      this.FormCar.controls['Brand'].setValue(Response.Brand);
      this.FormCar.controls['Model'].setValue(Response.Model);
      this.FormCar.controls['Color'].setValue(Response.Color);
      this.FormCar.controls['TopSpeed'].setValue(Response.TopSpeed);
    })
  }
```

And finally I binded it like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-1" (click)="EditCar(car.carId)">Edit</button>
```

In my CRUD application the create, delete, read is working. When I click on the button I get a error in my Google dev like this:

[image: screenshot]

The fields won't fill to edit but I get the ID. I have tried serveral solutions but it didn't work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the GET action result as you are getting error in that

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error in GET request. In **GET**, change `id=" + carId` to `/" + carId`

```
  getCarById(carId: string): Observable<CarVM> {
    return this.http.get<CarVM>(this.baseUrl + "/UpdateCar/" + carId)
  }
```

Also,Since **Angular5**, we don't need to pass `httpOptions`

Try like this:

```
 updateCar(carvm: CarVM): Observable<CarVM> {
    return this.http.put<CarVM>(this.baseUrl, carvm)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in the console shows the 405 Status Code which means:

`405 Method Not Allowed`

That usually points out that you are using the wrong HTTP Verb for your request.
You are making a GET request to an endpoint that is decorated with the `HttpPut` attribute, therefore expects a PUT request.

My guess is that `getCarById()` method binds to the wrong API endpoint on the server. (this one:
 `[Route("UpdateCar")]
 [HttpPut]
 public IActionResult Put([FromBody] Car car, long id)`